# Displaying Fizz Buzz to the screen

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have written JS script that console.logs the results of the the function Fizz Buzz. I have tried multiple ways using

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ...;
```

unfortunately I was only able to get Buzz to print to the screen. The JS code is below.

```
function fizz (num){

  for (var i = 0; i <= num; i++){
  var output = ""; 

  if(i % 3 === 0 ) {output += "Foo";}
  if(i % 5 === 0 ) {output += "Bar";}

  if(output ===""){output = i;}

  console.log(output)

   }

}

fizz(100)
```

The goal is to print the results to the screen where I can style the results in a legible way.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the html element 'ul' and append a new list item for every output.

I'll give you an example. In my HTML-Document, I will have an UL-Element with the ID "output"

```
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

That's it for the html-part for this task.

Your Javascript looks good. I'll use this to implement the append logic

```
function fizz (num){
   for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++){
     let element = document.createElement('li')
     element.innerText = "";
     if(i % 3 === 0 ) {element.innerText += "Fizz";}
     if(i % 5 === 0 ) {element.innerText += "Buzz";}
     if(element.innerText === ""){element.innerText = i;}
     document.getElementById('output').appendChild(element);
   }
}

fizz(100);
```

Full working version: https://codepen.io/araynimax/pen/pKpqWa

With the method `document.createElement()` You can create new HTML elements that you can fill with information and append it to another container. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)